# How to use PennySMS in c#.net?

Tags: c#, sms

Has anyone used PennySMS's web services? (https://www.pennysms.com/docs)  I'm having some difficulty doing a successful HttpPost request.

Update:
I'm a n00b to Web Services.  I don't even know if I can complete this type of request server-side.  I've replaced the actual info in the params with example info.

```
protected void bText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                    +"<methodCall>"
                    +"<methodName>send</methodName>"
                    +"    <params>"
                    +"        <param>"
                    + "            <value><string>MY KEY</string></value>"
                    +"        </param>"
                    +"        <param>"
                    + "            <value><string>service@example.com</string></value>"
                    +"       </param>"
                    +"       <param>"
                    + "           <value><string>555555555</string></value>"
                    +"       </param>"
                    +"       <param>"
                    +"          <value><string>Test Message</string></value>"
                    +"      </param>"
                    +"  </params>"
                    +"</methodCall>";
    SendText("http://api.pennysms.com/xmlrpc", "XML");
}
public void SendText(string _URL, string _parameters)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_URL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = _parameters;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the code that's failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. I've made no attemps to optimize anything. Unless the server restricts outgoing connections, you can use this server-side.

```
    protected static string DoRequest()
    {
        string XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
            +"<methodCall>"
            +"<methodName>send</methodName>"
            +"    <params>"
            +"        <param>"
            + "            <value><string>MY KEY</string></value>"
            +"        </param>"
            +"        <param>"
            + "            <value><string>service@example.com</string></value>"
            +"       </param>"
            +"       <param>"
            + "           <value><string>555555555</string></value>"
            +"       </param>"
            +"       <param>"
            +"          <value><string>Test Message</string></value>"
            +"      </param>"
            +"  </params>"
            +"</methodCall>";
        return SendText("http://api.pennysms.com/xmlrpc", XML);
    }
    public static string SendText(string _URL, string _parameters)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = _parameters;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        long responseLength = request.GetResponse().ContentLength;
        Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((int)responseLength);
        byteArray = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(byteArray, 0, 4096);                
        while(bytesRead > 0)
        {
            memStream.Write(byteArray, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(byteArray, 0, 4096);                
        }           
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the XML-RPC API, have you checked your content-type?  It should be "text/xml".